# sybase query plan OPEN CURSOR

Tags: sybase

Our system is accessed by another which selects `MAX()` of a column from a view that joins several big tables but returns only a few thousand rows.

Their query is slow, but when we attempt `sp_showplan`, only "OPEN CURSOR" is visible.

There must be a join order and index usage (there must be an entire plan somewhere), but we don't see it.

The monitor table appears just to store showplan.

Anyone with any ideas?  Maybe a dbcc of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

is MDA tables installed there.
if yes the did you check table monSysPlanText.

other way to check query paln,use below

set showplan on
write Query
go

There are  other option also which provide details
like:-

set statistics time on
set statistics io on
set statistics plancost on

Comment: Thanks, MDA is on but I need the DBA to enable sysplan monitoring. The only thing is I think this contains the same that sp_showplan would display, but I'll try.

Comment: The set commands - the thing is, this is another system connecting to ours.  They're the other side of an Oracle Gateway, so I'm assuming they can't do this.  Even if the gateway would pass through the "SET" commands, I think it would discard the Sybase server messages that are sent with the plan. But still - why not try and confirm that?  I'll ask them to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds likely that the client JDBC/ODBC setup has 'cursor' rather than direct enabled which wraps a cursor around all queries.

In terms of investigation you can also check syslocks for that spid whilst active and see which locks are being taken based on their object ID which should help you narrow down any tables and/or specific indexes being used.

If you do enable MDA then monOpenObjectActivity and monProcessActivity will also help.

Comment: Thanks very much Rich Campbell - I didn't know about the jdbc 'cursor' set-up, that does sound like it.  I knew the tables from syslocks but never did know the query plan - a few years have gone by!